# Expand/ Collapse Multi Select Labels (optgroup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, select

I made an example plnkr here: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBZVWIq7vOKVNC1K65f4?p=preview)

I would like to know if it is possible to make the bold labels expandable/collapsible? I ask because I've been trying to figure out how I can do this to where I only see the bold labels and on expand I see their content under them.

Below is the html code, JS and CSS

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <select multiple class="box">
    <optgroup ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
      <option ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    label: "My Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ]
    },{ 
    label: "My Other Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ] 
    }];



});
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/l9NNqkAZaBijR8OuDQhu?p=preview)

**Code:**

```
<select multiple class="box">
    <optgroup ng-click="value.expanded = !value.expanded" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
      <option ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-if="value.expanded" ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

$scope.data = [
 { label: "My Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], expanded: true },
 { label: "My Other Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], expanded: false }
];
```

**Changes:**

- Added `ng-if="value.expanded"` in each subvalue (you could use `ng-show` as well)
- Added `ng-click="value.expanded = !value.expanded"` on label level, to toggle visibility.
- Added default value for each label, in the controller (`expanded: true`)
- Added `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` to prevent selecting subgroups to collapse (If you need custom functionality on selecting, you should move this to a function)

Comment: you are awesome man! I don't why I didn't think of this at all

Comment: would I include ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right': value.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !value.expanded }" inside in optgroup?

Comment: well that wasn't part of the question but you can use the new variable to add css or whatever you want

Comment: cool, the only issue I'm going to have figure out now, is every time you select an option the labels collapse still

Comment: I could call a function in ng-change that can check for these value selections

Comment: @DrMints see my update. works now. Missed that one at first :P

Comment: yeah that works, I'm trying to fix a bug with it now. When you click and drag your selection it collapses the label. Possibly going to run a function on click of an option that will not only stopPropogation but continue to keep that label expand set to true until click of the label